# numtoyminterval get all employee who have not had review within 4 month of starting

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I've been given task to find all employees who have not had a review within 4 month of starting employment, but I need to use numtoyminterval.

I think I almost have it, but I cannot seem to work out how to get all employees who have not have review within 4 month of starting employment.

My code below returns all records.

Can anyone help with this.

```
SELECT Employee.ID,
       Employee.Surname,
       DateJoined.StartDate,
       Review.NextReviewDate
       numtoyminterval( months_between(DateJoined.StartDate, Review.NextReviewDate), 'month') as "EmployeeNotReviewed"
FROM   CompanyData 
       INNER JOIN
       Employee ON CompanyData.EmployeeID = Employee.EmployeeID 
       INNER JOIN
       DateJoined ON CompanyData.JoinedID = DateJoined.StartDate 
       INNER JOIN
       Review ON CompanyData.ReviewID = Review.Id
```

Comment: Why does it need to use `numtoyminterval`? The problem with that is that interval addition can cause an exception if you add, say four months to 2015-12-31 you get 2016-04-31, which isn't a valid date.

Comment: Hi Alex, not sure maybe that is what he wants me to discover, I've been here 6 mth and its been pretty tuff going.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Employee.ID,
       Employee.Surname,
       DateJoined.StartDate,
       Review.NextReviewDate
FROM   CompanyData 
       INNER JOIN
       Employee ON CompanyData.EmployeeID = Employee.EmployeeID 
       INNER JOIN
       DateJoined ON CompanyData.JoinedID = DateJoined.StartDate 
       INNER JOIN
       Review ON CompanyData.ReviewID = Review.Id
WHERE  MONTHS_BETWEEN( DateJoined.StartDate, Review.NextReviewDate ) >= 4
```

or

```
SELECT Employee.ID,
       Employee.Surname,
       DateJoined.StartDate,
       Review.NextReviewDate
FROM   CompanyData 
       INNER JOIN
       Employee ON CompanyData.EmployeeID = Employee.EmployeeID 
       INNER JOIN
       DateJoined ON CompanyData.JoinedID = DateJoined.StartDate 
       INNER JOIN
       Review ON CompanyData.ReviewID = Review.Id
WHERE  DateJoined.StartDate + NUMTOYMINTERVAL( 4, 'MONTH' )
         <= Review.NextReviewDate
```

The first option is better - try having a start date on `DATE '2015-10-30'` (then adding 4 months will be 30th February which will throw an exception `ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified`).

Comment: Hi MTO thanks, I will try it when I get to work tomorrow. Hopefully it will work.